# Swift bringSubViewToFront not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a number of labels and buttons on the screen. To act on user tapping anywhere on the screen, I have created a UIButton ("wholeScreenButton"), made its background clear and made it the same size as superview. Now at runtime I am using below code to bring the button on top of every other label.

```
self.wholeScreenButton.bringSubviewToFront(self.wholeScreenButton)
```

But it is not working. User can still tap on some of the buttons which are supposed to be underneath the wholeScreenButton and supposed to be unreachable.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It should be this:

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.wholeScreenButton)
```

You need to call bringSubviewToFront on the parent view.

Comment: How would you do this to a UIBarButton? @ronfessler

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
self.wholeScreenButton.superView.bringSubviewToFront(self.wholeScreenButton)
```

this ll work everytime for me

Comment: This is beating around the bush way. Simpler approach is self.view.bringSubviewToFront()

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 5.1**

view.bringSubviewToFront(self.wholeScreenButton)